# Substitute an npm package with own implementation

Tags: javascript, npm, yarnpkg

In my *package.json* I have a dependency `"protractor": "2.1.0"`. That package in turn depends on `"jasminewd2": "0.0.5"`.

That `jasminewd2` package has some behavior which I want to modify. I downloaded its sources and made the changes I need. [Yarn's documentation](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add) tells about a possibility to use a local source for packages:

> `yarn add file:/path/to/local/folder` installs a package that is on your local file system. This is useful to test out other packages of yours that haven’t been published to the registry.

When I execute that command

1. `"jasminewd2": "file:\\CustomNodeModules\\jasminewd2"` gets added to my *package.json*.
2. And this to my *yarn.lock* file:

   ```
   "file:\\CustomNodeModules\\jasminewd2", jasminewd2@0.0.5:
     name jasminewd2
     version "0.0.5"
     resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/jasminewd2
        /-/jasminewd2-0.0.5.tgz#528609a124dfc688c1e3f434a638e047066cd63e"
   ```

As a result, `node_modules/jasminewd2` contains the original version from the npm repository. How can I make yarn install my version instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe your solution doesn't work because `jasminewd2` is a transitive dependency (of `protractor`) and not a direct one. So when you add it directly, the transitive one isn't affected.

You can work around that using 3 approaches:

1. In case your change is temporary (meant for development or troubleshooting), you should `yarn link` as described in the [documentation](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/link).
2. Otherwise, you can fork both `protractor` and `jasminewd2` packages and reference them in the respective `package.json`s. `package.json`s  [syntax for that](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#dependencies) is `"protractor": "<githubUser>/<githubRepo>"`.
3. Using `yarn`'s `resolutions` [field](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/): `"resolutions": { "jasminewd2": "desired-version-or-url-or-path" }`. I know that PNPM has an equivalent feature too (but haven't used it myself).

From my experience, options 2 and 3 have a caveat in the form of the package manager cache: your git repo's `HEAD` is only pulled when that dependency is **first installed**. After that, it is kept cached and reinstalled every time - even when your repo's `HEAD` has changed.

The workaround is to reference a commit hash as part of the dependency like so: `"dependency": "user/repo.git#aef38fb2adc73304ae1ea87b0d607ad7fadc4d0g"`.

Comment: The problem with `link` is that nothing is written into package.json, therefore this manipulation has to be performed every time our CI server builds the project in a clean folder. In other words `yarn install` is suddenly not enough to prepare the build environment.

Comment: In that case I think your only option is to fork both `protractor` and `jasminewd2` packages and reference them in the respective `package.json`s. In case you're not familiar, [here's how](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#dependencies): `"protractor": "<githubUser>/<githubRepo>"`.

Comment: Thank you, that worked out. Can you modify your answer and include that second approach? I will accept it then.

Comment: @Monsignor done, and I added some more details :) Thanks!

Comment: One other good way to temporarily fix a package using Yarn 2 is to patch it with [`yarn patch`](https://yarnpkg.com/cli/patch).

Answer (score 2):

### Overriding a submodule using postinstall and git

The "*npm way*" requires a specific commit (or version/tag) to install a package from a git repository, [more info on npm install](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install). I usually create a custom branch and push on that, so I wanted the possibility to clone a custom branch for testing a specific feature or just leaving master alone.

To override a package I use the [postinstall hook](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) hook of npm.

I add a script to `postinstall` in `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "postinstall": "./postinstall.sh",
  "start": "node index.js"
},
```

Then I use a bash script (`postinstall.sh`) for removing packages and cloning them from github:

```
#!/bin/sh

function override_pkg {
  USER=$1
  REPO=$2
  DEST=$3

  rm -rf node_modules/$DEST

  echo "Overriding $DEST..."

  if [ -d custom_modules/$DEST ]; then
    cd custom_modules/$DEST
    git pull
    cd ../../
  else
    case $REPO in
      *:*)
      REPOBR=(${REPO//:/ })
      git clone -b ${REPOBR[1]} https://github.com/$USER/${REPOBR[0]}.git custom_modules/$DEST
      ;;
      *)
      git clone https://github.com/$USER/$REPO.git custom_modules/$DEST
      ;;
    esac
  fi

  npm install custom_modules/$DEST
}

# func       user    repo   branch dest
override_pkg johndoe myrepo:branch mynpmpackage
```

The script clones a package in the `custom_modules` folder, then it uses `npm` to install the local package to `node_modules`. The branch name after `:` is optional.

In the case of OP should be something like this:

```
override_pkg johndoe jasminewd:jasminewd2 jasminewd2
```

Then yarn:

```
yarn
```

If I do some local changes on the local git repository in `custom_modules\mypackage` I call `yarn` again for re-override the pacakge.

If I change machine and I got already a local version of my custom package, then calling `yarn` will pull from the repository and override the pacakge.

PS. `npm install` works too, but `yarn` is a bit faster.

### Multiple environments for testing purposes

This is a different idea, but sometimes I used it for testing different configurations. Maybe people can find it useful or if anyone knows a tool or something for doing this, please tell me.

Locally I create two distinct folders for `node_modules` like this:

First the original modules:

```
yarn --modules-folder=original-modules
```

Flags:

- `--modules-folder <path>` rather than installing modules into the `node_modules` folder relative to the cwd, output them here.

Then for the custom ones, I can simply copy `original-modules` for a clone:

```
cp -r original-modules custom-modules
```

Or I can use yarn to add more custom modules:

```
yarn add <modulename> --no-lockfile --modules-folder=custom-modules
```

Flags:

- `--no-lockfile` don't read or generate a lockfile

When I'm happy with the `custom-modules` folder I can switch between environments like this using [NODE_PATH](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_the_global_folders):

For the normal env:

```
NODE_PATH=original-modules npm start
```

Custom envrionment:

```
NODE_PATH=custom-modules npm start
```

It is important that the `node_modules` folder **does not exist** or the override will not work, the local `node_modules` folder has higher priority than `NODE_PATH`.