# Replace an npm package with an alternative

Tags: npm, module, package

Following up on [Substitute an npm package with own implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40398833/), which is about six years ago,
is there any simpler alternative now, with `npm` (not `yarn`, and not "transitive dependency")?

Basically, the same as [NPM replace package with other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62952450/npm-replace-package-with-other), I found that I need package XXX, however, that package XXX has been out of maintenance for a year now, and I've found an updated git repo (but with the same name of package XXX).

Is there any easy way for `npm` to grab from the alternative git repo instead, or any simpler workarounds? (Not to start a language war but `Go` now has)

That updated git repo owner must have a simple way to make use of his own package without publishing to npm, so what's the trick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`npm install` has a built in support to install package from github, gitlab, bitbucket, gist, and other special formats.

but you can install it from any git repository using the following

```sh
npm install <git repo url>
```

for more information, see [npm install](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-install) documentation